# Octave 4.4.1 fails to start on 32 bit Windows 7

Tags: octave

Octave 4.0.0 works on Windows 7 32 bit. I have just downloaded 4.4.1 and it has never worked.

Following information:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:     APPCRASH
  Application Name:       octave-gui.exe
  Application Version:    0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:  00000000
  Fault Module Name:      Qt5Core.dll
  Fault Module Version:   5.11.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp: 00000000
  Exception Code:         40000015
  Exception Offset:       002e8696
  OS Version:             6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:              3081
  Additional Information 1: d1e0
  Additional Information 2: d1e00fdc0b78c108f75564157f84c2f0
  Additional Information 3: f785
  Additional Information 4: f7855e1e76ad3f0614cfa9b98110597e
```

Found a vaguely similar problem, failing to start GUI on Windows 10, applied suggested solution of setting "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings" under Compatibility tab of executable Properties.

Comment: Forgot to say final part made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you download GNU octave from octave.org you'll see a list:

1. Windows-64 (recommended)

   - octave-4.4.1-w64-installer.exe (~ 238 MB) [signature]
   - octave-4.4.1-w64.7z (~ 267 MB) [signature]
   - octave-4.4.1-w64.zip (~ 481 MB) [signature]
2. Windows-32 (old computers)

   - octave-4.4.1-w32-installer.exe (~ 238 MB) [signature]
   - octave-4.4.1-w32.7z (~ 267 MB) [signature]
   - octave-4.4.1-w32.zip (~ 481 MB) [signature]

Of couse a 64bit built will **NOT run** on a Windoze7 32bit so you have to get octave-4.4.1-w32-installer.exe and install this